# Is this function an orthogonal projection?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $(g \otimes h)(x,y) = g(x)\overline{h(y)}$ denote the tensor product of two measurable functions. Suppose we have the kernel $k(x,y) = e^{2\pi i(x-y)}$ on $[0,1]^2$. We want to show that the function $O_k: L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ given by $$O_kf(x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) \, dy,$$ is an orthogonal projection. My attempt to this solution is that we can write $k(x,y)=g \otimes g$, where $g(x) = e^{2 \pi ix}$. Given this we can write $$O_kf(x) = \int_0^1 g(x)\overline{g(y)}f(y)\,dy = (f,g)g(x),$$ where $(f,g)$ is the scalar product. Is this enough to show that $O_k$ is an orthogonal projection, since it projects to the span of $g$? Thank u!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In any Hibert space $Tx=\langle x, y \rangle y$ defines  an orthogonal projection onto the one-dimensional space spanned by $y$ if $y$ is vector of norm $1$.